# Inserting rows into SQL with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

So my problem is, I'm getting an error message while writing this instert query in to my SQL server. I'm using Visual Studie 2017. Error message:

> `System.ArgumentException`: 'There is no allocation object type `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputGenericControl` to a known native type of a managed service provider.'

This happends on my `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` but I've tried `Scalar` and `Reader`. All giving an error.

I really hope some one has a solution, it's for a college project.

```
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["csPAD"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        string Study = rbStudy.SelectedValue;

        string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO Registratie ([Firstname], [middlename], [Lastname], [Dateofbirth], [Study], [Email]) VALUES (@Firstname,@middlename,@Lastname,@Dateofbirth,@Study,@Email)";
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, myConnection)
        {

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", txtFirstname.Text);
            if (txtmiddlename.Text == "")
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlename", "");
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlename", txtmiddlename.Text);
            }
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", txtLastname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dateofbirth", Dateofbirth);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Study", Study);
            if (txtEmail.Text == "")
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", "");
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
            }        
            myConnection.Open();
            int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show(rows + " rows affected!");
            myConnection.Close();                             
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        lblNotification.Text = "Everything is required.";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `Dateofbirth` object?

Comment: Side note: The if statements for `middlename` and `Email` are pointless

Comment: Does `connString` have the correct value?

Comment: Can you post the actual code, it looks like this code doesn't compile

Comment: Slight detour...you should be explicit with your datatypes when doing ad hoc queries like this. The datatype will not always be determined correctly. Especially with dates. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ You should also get in the habit of wrapping your connection and command objects with a USING statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make below changes to your Asp.net and C# code

> Replace

```
<input type="date" ID="DateofBirth" runat="server" min="01-01-1990" max="01-01-2020">
```

WITH

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="DateofBirth" runat="server"></ asp:TextBox>
```

AND

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dateofbirth", Dateofbirth.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

@David The following code is in my  HTML page:

```
<td><asp:Label ID="lblDateofBirth" runat="server" Text="DateofBirth:"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><input type="date" ID="DateofBirth" runat="server" min="01-01-1990" max="01-01-2020"></td>
            <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDateofBirth" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DateofBirth" ErrorMessage="Dit veld is vereist!" ForeColor="Red" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
```

And this is configured in my Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="csPAD" connectionString="Data Source=MARCO-LAPTOP;Initial Catalog=ProjectPAD;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

For the which asked for full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Windows.Forms;


public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["csPAD"].ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                string Study = rbStudy.SelectedValue;

                string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO Registratie ([Firstname], [middlename], [Lastname], [Dateofbirth], [Study], [Email]) VALUES (@Firstname,@middlename,@Lastname,@Dateofbirth,@Study,@Email)";
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, myConnection)
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", txtFirstname.Text);
                    if (txtmiddlename.Text == "")
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlename", "");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middlename", txtmiddlename.Text);
                    }
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", txtLastname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dateofbirth", Dateofbirth);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Study", Study);
                    if (txtEmail.Text == "")
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", "");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
                    }        
                    myConnection.Open();
                    int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show(rows + " rows affected!");
                    myConnection.Close();                             
                }
            }
            else
            { 
                lblNotification.Text = "Everything is required.";
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it like this?

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into tbl_insert values(@name,@email,@add)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add", txtadd.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score -2):

My guess is that you need to fix the following line (Dateofbirth seems to be a control name ?) :

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dateofbirth", Dateofbirth);
```

Comment: `Study` is of type `string` as can be seen in the code.

Comment: Sorry , meant date of birth (fixed it just now)